# Accessing CPU Registers from C

Tags: c, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

Recently I have been playing around with inline assmbly in C, and was wondering if I could directly access a register from a variable

Something like this:

```
volatile uint64_t* flags = RFLAGS;
```

Where RFLAGS is the CPUs flags register. Obviously, the above code doesn't compile, but I was wondering if there was a similar way to achieve the desired result.

Compiling for Ubuntu x86_64 with gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, certainly.  You can `PUSHF`, `PUSHFD` or `PUSHFQ` the flags and them pop them into another register.  For example:

```
unsigned int flags;
__asm{
  pushfd
  pop edx
  mov flags, edx
}
```

For gcc under Ubuntu using AT&T syntax, you may find the following more immediately useable:

```
unsigned int flags:
__asm__("pushf\n\t"
        "pop edx\n\t"
        "movl edx, flags");
```

From there you can view them at your leisure!

Comment: This answer is for MSVC, Turbo C, or some other compiler that can't be used for the OP's system. And it's generally wrong. You cannot meaningfully access flags from inline asm **unless the flags are produced by asm instructions in the same asm block**. You certainly can't get the results from C arithmetic.

Comment: I don't disagree that the flags will only reflect the status in the current function and context and that it would be best to use assembly only if you actually care about them, but it is incorrect to flatly state that this is "generally wrong."  Since the format of the code offends you, however, I'll gladly add a GCC compatible version.

Comment: The gcc version is still wrong. It's obtaining the flags **at some random point during the execution of the function**. What the OP wants is not possible because there is no way to specify "the flags from arithmetic operation X" as an input constraint to inline asm. Also note that you can't just access variables by name from asm.

Comment: I don't think my comments were sufficiently clear to explain my objections, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain the value of the flags register via inline asm, but this operation is not useful because you have no control over sequencing of the access with respect to other operations. In particular, what you likely want is for the flags resulting from some particular arithmetic operation to be available at the beginning of your asm block, but there is no way in which to express that constraint to the compiler. For example, suppose you wrote:

```
z = x + y;
__asm__ ( "pushf ; pop %0" : "=r"(flags) );
```

You might expect the flags resulting from the addition to be available. However, the compiler may have chosen to:

- reorder the arithmetic after the asm, since neither has a result that depends on the other.
- adjust the stack pointer with `add`/`sub` in between, clobbering the flags.
- use `lea` instead of `add` to implement the addition, producing no flags.
- omit the addition entirely based on determination that the result is not used.
- etc.

The same principle applies for accessing any register that might be modified by the code the compiler generates. There **is** a syntax (in GCC/"GNU C") for accessing registers not subject to this issue; it looks like:

```
register int var __asm__("regname");
```

where `regname` is replaced by the name of the register. This is largely useless on most targets, but it can allow you to control register usage for input/output constraints to asm, and some targets have special values kept permanently in general purpose registers (the thread-local-storage pointer is the most common) which could be useful in some situations.

Comment: While you're totally correct that accessing the status flags set by compiler-generated arithmetic instructions would be completely useless (as there's no telling *what* will have set them), and it would likewise be foolish to meddle with the direction flag DF (as the compiler-generated code may need it set the other way), it *could* be useful to read the system flags. (But only rarely, and in practice, this only happens when some full-blooded assembler code -- entry{,_32,_64}.S, say -- will already have stashed the registers somewhere convenient.) Yes, I'm a nitpicker.